# Can I Use Application Web Services Which is Already Made for Android in iOS especially in push notification

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apns-php

Is their any difference between web services for android and iOS ?? especially if i am implementing push notification using google cloud messaging

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Web services

There shouldn't be any major differences between web services for `Android` and `iOS`. Especially when it comes to exchanging `JSON` with object representations. At the end, it's all the same, parsing and mapping. Sometimes you might want to return some special, platform specific information. In this case, the mobile clients need a way to tell your backend which `OS` they're running.

#### Push notifications

Push notifications is a different story. On Android you have `Google Cloud Messaging` and on iOS `Apple Push Notification Service`. Your back end has to know which notification service to use.

There are many ways to solve this problem.
One way is to set a custom `HTTP` header that would contain information about the `OS` the mobile client runs. Another is to have a parameter that is sent with each request.